# Can't set value of location_providers_allowed using "adb shell settings put"

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to turn location on using the following commands:

```
adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed gps,wifi,network
adb reboot
```

But it's neither changing the value of the variable *location_providers_allowed* nor turning it on under Android Settings UI after the reboot.

I tried the same command to set other variables, like mock_location, and it worked without problems.
Is this variable not possible to be changed?

Android version: M

Answer (score 5):

For Android 6.0

To Enable use :

For GPS : `adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed +gps`

For Network : `adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed +network`

To Disable :

GPS : `adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed -gps`

For Network : `adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed -network`

Answer (score 4):

I have yet to solve this problem, but wanted to provide additional information that I feel is relevant and may help somebody else solve this.

I tried to follow [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40147/is-it-possible-to-enable-location-services-via-shell/114033#114033), but it was mentioned in one of the comments that:

> This used to work on Android 5, but it doesn't anymore on Android 6. With or without root the setting does not change and stays the same as is configured on the system. It probably has something to do with location_providers_allowed being deprecated (developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/…) – gw0 Nov 4 '15 at 7:45

I looked into the docs for [Settings.Secure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED) `location_providers_allowed` and sure enough:

> This constant was deprecated in API level 19. use LOCATION_MODE and MODE_CHANGED_ACTION (or PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)

I tried to set `location_mode` but had no effect on enabling/disabling location services.

When turning on/off location services manually through the `location_providers_allowed` flag is affected, not `location_mode`. I find it weird that the docs say it's deprecated, but it's still used and `location_mode` 
isn't.

*That's all I got.*

Comment: Still seems to be the same situation in 2020, except now it seems like `location_providers_allowed` is also not working reliably, so there's basically just no way to enable location reliably by shell now.

Answer (score 1):

From Android 6 up-to Android 9 you can manipulate "location_providers_allowed" if you have WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission.

From Android 10, this has no effect whatsoever as described here (search Android Q): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED

There is a new API, but it doesn't have any public way to change any settings: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#isProviderEnabled(java.lang.String)

Maybe with root or as system app, one can access this:

```
@SystemApi
@TestApi
@RequiresPermission(WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS)
public void setProviderEnabledForUser(String provider, boolean enabled, @NonNull UserHandle userHandle);
```

EDIT: This work perfectly as system app. Haven't tried with root.

Comment: Hey @3c71 I want to use this from system app can you provide any example?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by pulling /data/system/users/0/settings_secure.xml

change value in the xml of the setting below to gps,network or what you want

```
<setting id="0" name="location_providers_allowed" value="" package="android" />
```

than push it back to same place and reboot

Comment: But doesn't it need root? I think Yes!