# adb command to GPS (Setting > Location) enable in marshmallow

Tags: adb, android-6.0-marshmallow

Using command

adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed gps

I can enable the location in Android 5.1.1

But if I use the same command in android 6, It is not working

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243361/cant-set-value-of-location-providers-allowed-using-adb-shell-settings-put/37819652

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution Found on supersu log of power toggles, works on mm:
Enable GPS 
"settings put secure location_providers_allowed +gps"

Enable network location 
"settings put secure location_providers_allowed +network"

Disable GPS 
"settings put secure location_providers_allowed -gps"
Disabling network location 
"settings put secure location_providers_allowed -network"

Comment: It is working like a charm on my LineageOS (Android 7.1.2). Thank you all